# Uncertainty formula if measured "best" value is zero

Tags: uncertainty

If the uncertainty of a function $f(x,y)$ is given by:

$$\delta f = |f_{best}|\sqrt{ \left( \frac{\delta x}{x_{best}} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\delta y}{y_{best}} \right)^2}$$

what do we do if $x_{best}$ or $y_{best}$ are zero? Presumably, $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ need not be zero.

Comment: The formula you're using is not suitable for the kind of case you're applying it to.

Comment: @Glen_b Cool. Do you mind elaborating a little? Or providing a link?

Comment: @Glen_b What is the equation one should use in that case...?

Comment: Such formulas rely on assumptions; you've violated the assumptions of the one you used, but you don't indicate which assumptions *should* apply. [Further, with variables that can be non-positive, I'd suggest you probably want to consider absolute error rather than relative error.]

Comment: By the way, can you say where your formula came from? Did they explain anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

you don't use relative error in this case: $\delta f=\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2}$

Comment: Cool. Do you mind elaborating just a bit? I know a little math, but I'm a total rookie when it comes to stats.

Comment: Or if you can provide a link, that'd be okay too.

Comment: For a standard guide in uncertainty propagation, see the [GUM](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf), Section 5.

Comment: @Pascal The link you shared has deprecated.